# Permission denied for ls /usr/bin on windows subsystem for linux

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1703

`ls /usr/bin`

gives the error message:

`ls: reading directory '/usr/bin': Permission denied`

on `wbash.exe`. For that reason bash-completion and eshell-completion fails or gives incomplete results. I would like to get it working.

Things that do work:

```
/usr/bin $ ls -l emacs
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root           root           23 2017-07-31 17:16 emacs -> /etc/alternatives/emacs
/usr/bin $ ls -l gcc-5
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           root       915736 2017-09-14 06:01 gcc-5
/usr/bin $ ls -ld /usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   0 root           root          512 2017-12-19 09:45 /usr/bin
/usr/bin $ ls -ld /usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   0 root           root          512 2017-12-19 09:45 /usr/sbin
/usr/bin $ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x   0 root           root          512 2017-11-17 10:23 /
/usr/bin $ ls -ld /usr
drwxr-xr-x   0 root           root          512 2017-03-30 11:55 /usr
```

Windows version is: Windows 10 (64bit), Version 1703 (Build 15063.786)

The `sbin` directory can be listed without problems and all windows settings of `bin` in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr` available via WindowsExplorer are the same as that ones for `sbin`.

The commands `icacls.exe bin` and `icacls.exe sbin` within `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr` give exactly the same answer (up to the first word which is `bin` for `bin` and `sbin` for `sbin`). So it does not seem to be related to the extra attributes. Also the commands `icacls.exe bin /verify` and `icacls.exe sbin /verify` don't indicate any errors.

Is there maybe some security-related feature of ubuntu (I don't know of) that prohibits me to list the directory contents of `/usr/bin`? (In that case it would be strange if it didn't forbid the listing of `/usr/sbin`.)

Comment: what it the output of `ls -ld /` and `ls -ld /usr` ?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I added those two to the list. Nothing surprising there.

Comment: So it seems to be because of extra attributes, look e.g. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The commands `icacls.exe bin` and `icacls.exe sbin` give exactly the same answer (up to the first word which is `bin` for `bin`and `sbin` for `sbin`). So it does not seem to be related to the extra attributes. Is that right? Or are there some nifty tricks to get even more information?  `icacls.exe bin /verify` and  `icacls.exe sbin /verify` doesn't output any errors.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I can list the contents of `bin` (and `sbin`) without problems under windows (e.g., WindowsExplorer or PowerShell `dir bin` or `ls bin`)

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/ls /usr/bin` give different results? (I'm starting to think it is a bug of build-in ls so with wbash). Ev. you can check if you have a special alias.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi `/bin/ls /usr/bin` gives also a `permission denied` and the `ls` from `eshell` I am working on is built into `eshell` and does not use the `wbash` `ls`. I also tried `ls` on `wbash` with the same results.

Comment: I think you have managed to set your permissions in such a way that the shell cannot access these folders.These permissions might be in Windows, rather than in the shell.

Comment: @Biswa First of all: Thanks to all who tried to help. I tried to add my user to group `sudo` with the proposed command. `groups` shows `sudo` among others. Pityingly it does not help to solve the problem.

Comment: @harrymc After all the tests I performed and cited in my question (especially with `icacls.exe`) do you still think that this can be a permission problem on Windows level? I can list the folder contents without problems from within Windows (e.g., `powershell` and `WindowsExplorer`).

Comment: Based on your info, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like a permissions problem.

As you have verified that the problem is not with Windows,
then this problem is with WSL internal settings,
where it emulates Linux permissions which do not natively exist on Windows.

I don't know exactly how WSL does its emulation of Linux permissions.
If it uses the Windows mechanism of ACL, you could reset them all by :

```
icacls %localappdata%\lxss /reset /T /C
```

If this does not help,
and without better knowledge of how these permissions are implemented,
I would suggest to reinstall WSL :

1. Backup your data
2. Uninstall the Ubuntu environment but keep your home folder, then
   reinstall WSL, by using the commands :

   ```
   lxrun /uninstall
   lxrun /install
   ```
3. If this did not help, fully reinstall the Ubuntu environment
   including removing your home folder, by entering :

   ```
   lxrun /uninstall /full
   lxrun /install
   ```

In-between the two above commands, check that the folder
`%localappdata%\lxss` is empty.
If not, move its contents to temporary storage and delete later
when no longer required.

Comment: Lxrun is deprecated now.

Comment: @Biswa: This is for the upcoming Windows build 16215. lxrun is the current method, and most likely will continue to be available for some time.

Answer (score 0):

There are no permission problems with cygwin under `$HOME/AppData/Local/lxss/rootfs/usr/bin` and I did some tests with playground folders of wsl under cygwin. That lead me to the following solution.

In the bash of cygwin I went to `$HOME/AppData/Local/lxss/rootfs/usr` and run the following command:

```
find bin -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "cp -a %p fix/%p\n" > /temp/fix.sh
```

That created a script `/temp/fix.sh` in a folder `/temp` that is shared between cygwin and wsl via symbolic links.

In `wbash` I went to `/usr/`, created the folders `fix` and `fix/bin`, run the script, and moved the directory `fix/bin` to `bin-fix`.

```
cd /usr
mkdir -p fix/bin
. /temp/fix.sh
mv fix/bin bin-fix
```

Thereby, `wbash` told me that it had permission problems for `bin/head`.
Okay, I accepted that and re-installed `coreutils` as a last step of this procedure (see below).
Next I closed all `wbash` applications and `wbash` itself and went back to cygwin where the `usr` folder was still open.

There I moved `bin` out of the way and re-named `bin-fix` to `bin`.

```
mv bin bin.old
mv bin-fix bin
```

I re-started `wbash` and voilá everything runs fine and `ls /usr/bin` works.

As I already mentioned above I re-installed `coreutils` as a last step:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall coreutils
```